# javascript file with absolute file path

Tags: javascript, absolute-path

I am adding a javascript file dynamically with absolute file path like..

```
<script src="file://C:/Users/Darshan/Desktop/MyApp/Jar_18_9/UserWidgets/elements/NewElement.js"></script>
```

That file contains a function like

```
function test_call_NewElement(){
    alert("Called");
}
```

Even I can see this function availability using firebug..
but when I called that function from other function I get a error like test_call_NewElement is not defined?

Cant we use the absolute path like this..?

Comment: Provide a little more of the HTML markup, please. Is this script loaded before or after the one that calls the function?

Comment: This script will be loaded before any one calls that function and it works fine if I add this script statically like every other scripts.. On dynamic addition problem is occurring..

Comment: You really should not use the file system to serve up webpages. There are a lot of restrictions.